# Why does my shell script exit after changing users?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create this little script to basically recreate the steps I take everytime I start a new ubuntu machine and install some python project on it. At one point the script stops. Which is when I switch to the postgres user. It never runs the `psql` commands

```
pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
useradd -m -p $2 $1
sudo -i -u postgres
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $1;"
psql -c "CREATE USER $1 WITH PASSWORD '$2';"
psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $1 to $1;"
```

I probably suck bash scripting and I am trying to get better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the command

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

a *new* shell is spawned. If you type `exit` at this point, this new shell will exit and your original shell will continue running the `psql` commands (but not as the `postgres` user).

You can do the following to fix this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $1;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER $1 WITH PASSWORD '$2';"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $1 to $1;"
```